# How to convert color to (x, y) coordinate on color palette and slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I made a color picker, it's fully functional and does what it's supposed to do.
I want to add an input box where users can insert any color value HEX, RGBA, HSLA.
Now I'm trying to get the value the user entered, and change the slider and the 'cursor' in the color palette to the correct location.

This is what my color palette looks like and its values / possibly important information;
and just to point out the 'cursor' im talking about is @ top right of the color palette, and slider ofcourse is the rainbow range input
[image]

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please mention the code you have already tried

Comment: Use this -- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281162/scale-a-number-between-a-range/281164 Substitude the actual pixel width/height with the elements width/height, and you should map between 0 and 1. Then you just multiply by 255 to get the hex value. `0 x 255 = 0` and `1 * 255 = 255.`

Comment: Don't forget to round as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved issue by converting the value the user has entered to HSV.
I replaced the max value for the hue range to 360 and set the hue to the h value of the hsv.
The s value I appended a '%' and assigned it to the 'cursor''s left value
The v value I first did `100 - v` and appended a '%' too and assigned it to the 'cursor''s top value[image]